# Access Django from outside Django shell in real Python

Tags: python, django, shell

I run Django through a Python 3.4 virtualenv and I want to make some cronjob scripts that will access models and save.

I can do this through the Django shell `python manage.py shell` will initiate the Django shell. From there I can do `from polls.models import Poll, Choice` and make a new Poll and save it into the DB.

How can I do this through the regular Python shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to create a management command. You can run it from the command line by calling (python manage.py ) and from within the script you can access any django functions or models.

For further instructions on how see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Awesome. Just what I was looking for. Didn't even know you can do this.